# -805306369 (0xCFFFFFFF) error in python what can i do

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, exit-code

I'm quite new to python and have recently started game dev with pygame. I wanted to know why my game just freezes and the exitcode -805306369 (0xCFFFFFFF) appears. Do i have errors in my programm? It looks like this:

```
import pygame
import random
import math

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((1000, 600))
caption = pygame.display.set_caption(
    'Test your reaction speed. Shoot the target game!')  # sets a caption for the window
run = True
PlayerImg = pygame.image.load('F:\PythonPortable\oscn.png')
PlayerX = 370
PlayerY = 420
PlayerX_change = 0
PlayerY_change = 0


def player():
    window.blit(PlayerImg, (PlayerX, PlayerY))


aim_sight = pygame.image.load('F:\PythonPortable\ktarget.png')
aim_sightX = 460
aim_sightY = 300
aim_sight_changeX = 0
aim_sight_changeY = 0


def aim_sight_function(x, y):
    window.blit(aim_sight, (x, y))


targetedImg = pygame.image.load('F:\PythonPortable\ktargetedperson.png')
targetedX = random.randint(0, 872)
targetedY = random.randint(0, 200)


def random_target():
    window.blit(targetedImg, (targetedX, targetedY))


def iscollision(targetedX, targetedY, aim_sightX, aim_sightY):
    distance = math.sqrt((math.pow(targetedX - aim_sightX, 2)) + (math.pow(targetedY - aim_sightY, 2)))
    if distance < 70:
        return True
    else:
        return False
while run:
    window.fill((255, 255, 255))
    random_target()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                aim_sight_changeX = -2
                PlayerX_change = -2
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                aim_sight_changeX = 2
                PlayerX_change = 2
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                aim_sight_changeY = -2
                PlayerY_change = -2
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                aim_sight_changeY = 2
                PlayerY_change = 2
            score = 0
            while score < 10:
                collision = iscollision(targetedX, targetedY, aim_sightX, aim_sightY)
                if collision and event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    print("HIT") # Just for me to acknowledge that collision is true and space bar was pressed in the right spot
                    score = score + 1
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                aim_sight_changeX = 0
                PlayerX_change = 0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                aim_sight_changeY = 0
                PlayerY_change = 0
    aim_sightX += aim_sight_changeX
    if aim_sightX <= 46.5:
        aim_sight_changeX = 0
    elif aim_sightX >= 936:
        aim_sight_changeX = 0
    aim_sightY += aim_sight_changeY
    if aim_sightY <= 0:
        aim_sight_changeY = 0
    elif aim_sightY >= 400:
        aim_sight_changeY = 0

    PlayerX += PlayerX_change
    if PlayerX <= -50:
        PlayerX_change = 0
    elif PlayerX >= 850:
        PlayerX_change = 0

    player()
    aim_sight_function(aim_sightX, aim_sightY)
    pygame.display.update()
```

I think there is a mistake in this area as my program runs well without it.

```
 while score < 10:
                collision = iscollision(targetedX, targetedY, aim_sightX, aim_sightY)
                if collision and event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    print("HIT") # Just for me to acknowledge that collision is true and space bar was pressed in the right spot
                    score = score + 1
```

I've checked other questions but they are mostly for java and other languages.

Comment: You have an infinite loop in the case where `score` is not modified.

Comment: `while score < 10:` -> `if score < 10:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an application loop. You do not need an additional loop to control the game. The loop that increments the score is an infinite loop. Change the loop to a selection (change `while` to `if`).
Furthermore, the score has to be initialized before the application loop:

```py
score = 0
while run:
    # [...]

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                aim_sight_changeX = -2
                PlayerX_change = -2
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                # [...]

            elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                if score < 10:
                    collision = iscollision(targetedX, targetedY, aim_sightX, aim_sightY)
                    if collision:
                        print("HIT") 
                        score = score + 1
```

Comment: That wont work in terms of adding one to the score each time. Ive refurbished the programm so the target respawns but the score isnt gonna work without a while or for loop. right?

Comment: @Ght007 Of course the score works without an extra loop. You have a loop. You have the application loop. `while run:` is your loop. What do you mean by "adding one to the score each time."? You have to hit  "SPACE" in the right moment. Are you searching for a solution where you can hold down "SPACE"?